# itextPDF digital signature on PDF doc

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I am having issue creating digital signature for PDF document from byte array that is signature. I wrote this code and got stuck on what to do next:

```
public void sign(String src, String dest, SignResultWS signResult, String reason, String location)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setReason(reason);
        sap.setLocation(location);
        sap.setContact(signResult.getFirstName() + " " + signResult.getLastName());
        sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");

        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.setReason(sap.getReason());
        dic.setLocation(sap.getLocation());
        dic.setContact(sap.getContact());
        dic.setDate(new PdfDate(sap.getSignDate()));
        sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
}
```

Do I need to use next this method:

```
MakeSignature.signDetached(sap, digest, es, ?, ?,?, ?, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

My main problem is that I cannot figure how to put this byte array in PDF.
Thanks in advance!